# UITableView header not displaying correctly after update to underlying data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have been experiencing strange behavior with the header drawing the first time.  Here are the steps I go through and it is reproducible every time.

- Go to Tab 2.  Select an item to download.
- Download completes and imports data into CoreData database, which
  is linked to the TableView on Tab 1
  (shown).
- I do make the following calls on the TableView:

}

```
-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller {
    [self.setsTableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller {
    [self.setsTableView endUpdates];
}
```

- Go to Tab 1 and the header for the 1st section is displayed incorrectly.

As soon as I move the TableView scroll up or down, the problem immediately resolves itself.  Also, if I quit the app and go back in, the header is displayed correctly.

I have drawn a red box around the problem area.

Anyone ever see this behavior before?

[image: strange header behavior]

Notice the difference in how the header is displayed below.  This is how it SHOULD look from the start.  All I do between screenshot 1 (above) and screenshot 2 (below) is scroll the UITableView.

[image: this is how it SHOULD look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest build of iOS, this problem seems to have gone away.  I never did find a solution to it.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. I'm using Xcode 4.1, and it happens on the simulator and the device. What build resolved it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to reload the table when the new data is available 
using this method.
this is running on main thread, UI are only run on main thread

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.tableview reloadData];

                });
```

it's update..............

Comment: Calling `reloadData` causes the animation to stop and looks bad. I can call it once the animation completes using `CATransaction` but it still jitters a bit.